# Unity not updating global variable when updated from function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i am having trouble updating my vector2 data from my function.
The objective of this vector2 is to save the dead enemy position but when i use it globally it goes to 0,0 when inside the function it has the right values.

Heres is the code

```
 private Vector2 enemyPosition;

void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("enemyPosition update: " + enemyPosition);
    gameObject.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, enemyPosition, blobSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

public void createBlobMelee(GameObject enemy)
{
    enemyPosition = new Vector2(enemy.transform.position.x, enemy.transform.position.y);
    Debug.Log("enemyPosition: " + enemyPosition);
    randomBlobx = Random.Range(-1, 1);
    randomBloby = Random.Range(-1, 1);
    Vector2 randomBlobCreate = new Vector2(enemy.transform.position.x + randomBlobx, enemy.transform.position.y + randomBloby);
    Instantiate(gameObject, randomBlobCreate, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

And this is the results from the debug console.

[image: Debug console]

Thank you for you time,
André Sousa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your object as

`public static Vector2 enemyPosition;`

If it can not be static try `public` or try just `static`.

I have this problem very often, you just need to play with the `public` and `static` and see what works for you.

Comment: although this is working now, it would be good to note as soon as you have more than one blob it won't work anymore and both bobs will share their position

Comment: I've never had this but it would be really good to know what causes this. I high advise you not fix this by making it static though. Enemy is something that there is very likely to be many of and static should only be used when you know that you only want one version of that variable in all places.

Comment: Access level should have no bearing on how it's accessed from within the same class/object. Something interesting must be happening because that's just not how C# works.

Comment: He did not show where he calls the createBlobMelee function from

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the `public` and `private` setting.

For more information look [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/33828/public-or-private.html)